# How to Hide / Show Wordpress Admin Bar from Theme Settings Panel

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using Redux Framework and Trying to Activate or Deactivat wordpress admin bar with this function

```
if( !function_exists('mytheme_admin_bar') ){
function mytheme_admin_bar(){
global $optname; 
if( $optname['hide_admin_bar'] == 1 && !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
return true;
    } else {
return false;
  }
}
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , 'mytheme_admin_bar');
}
```

Thats working fine but Im confused because when The value is false its hiding the admin bar also for Administrator do u have any idea how to make a function like this but to effect to all users except Administrator, I dont want to hide admin bar for admins

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the user is admin. So here is a wrapper

```html
if (is_admin()) { 

  add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , true);


 } else {
  add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , false);
}
```

Basically you are checking if the user is not an admin than fire this code snippet. Hope it helps.

Comment: NIck Thankyou verymuch but I tried and the same so the code is working like before, so when I use the 0 value it must hide only for normal users but also in this way when Im logged in as admin in frontend the adminbar is hidden.I want admin bar visible for admin also if the option has  value 0

Comment: Yes also this one I have tried before and I added global `$optname; if( $optname['hide_admin_bar'] == 1 && !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {` because Im trying to controll it from redux panel, however the option is working with the previous code. Let me explain it: I have an option in theme settings Admin Bar ON/OFF on is 1 off is 0 when I check off I want to disable adminbar for all users exept admin this is all Im sorry for my bad english and thanks for your help But the last code stays allways hidden for all users

Comment: Just did another test using `} else { remove_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , true);` but no luck

Comment: Try echoing the output of $optname['hide_admin_bar'] variable if it is really giving desired value. I had a similar problem with redux once.

Comment: and try add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' ); or set functions' return variable to '__return_false'

Answer (score 0):

I typically add the following to the themes functions.php file.

wp-content/themes/themename/functions.php

```
show_admin_bar(false);
```

This removes it from the front end totally, for that theme - provided simply as a fallback here since it's not exactly what you're asking!

Comment: yes this one was working but I had problems with the white space and some other issues.And I dont want to hide it totaly I want to keep it visible for admins to have the links as edit post etc..

Comment: Hey thanks, I tried to explain it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36884500/how-to-hide-show-wordpress-admin-bar-from-theme-settings-panel/36885421?noredirect=1#comment61336710_36885421

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, it doesn't hide it for Administrator

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```